# Pymongo using hint on find_one gets AttributeError

Tags: pymongo

Im need to preform a mongodb find_one query with pymongo but get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hint' since there are no results matching the filter

`db.collection_name.find_one( filter=filter_query, projection={ _id: False, date: True, }, sort=[ ( date, pymongo.DESCENDING, ) ], ).hint('some_index')`
also tried

`db.collection_name.find_one( filter=filter_query, projection={ _id: False, date: True, }, sort=[ ( date, pymongo.DESCENDING, ) ], hint='some_index'`
)
I know I can do it with find() but is there a way to do it with find_one?

Comment: What is the output/error with the second `find_one` you show?

Answer (score 0):

The first approach definitely won't work. The second requires the hint parameter to be passed in the same format used to create the index, e.g. `[('field', ASCENDING)]`.

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find